# Laravel 8 route with multiple parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to use multiple parameters in route in Laravel 8 but for some reason it does not work.

**My web.php**

```
    Route::get('/mp3/{name}/{album]/{track}' , [TracksController::class, 'trackDetails'])->name('trackDetails')
->where([
    'name' => '[a-z]+',
    'album' => '[a-z]+',
    'name' => '[a-z]+'
])
```

**My controller**

```
public function trackDetails ($name, $album, $track)
    {
        return view('mp3.trackdetails', [
            'name' => $name,
            'album' => $album,
            'track' => $track,
        ]);
    }
```

I have created the blade view with a simple title but I get 404 error.
Am I missing something? I want to generate a url like example.com/mp3/artist/album/track

Comment: The `album` parameter should be closed with a `}` not with `]`. Also, maybe the last constraint should be `track` instead of `name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have error in route parameter.

remove ] after album and change with }